# Create a new wiki page using the 2013 Client Library

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, wiki

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 Client Library and am trying to generate new wiki articles.

I'm able to connect, retrieve the web, find the list, but I can't add items. I feel like I need to be using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing, since I am really trying to create a publishing page, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://mosspractice.example.com/sites/DocDemo/");
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documentation");

context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
newItem["Title"] = "Peter API Test 1";
newItem["Page Content"] = "Hello World!";
newItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery(); //errors saying Title is not a valid column name...
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working example at. https://web.archive.org/web/20150710164136/http://spdevlab.com/2013/03/28/creating-wiki-web-part-and-publishing-pages-via-csom-in-sharepoint-2010/. This example worked on the first try without issue.

Comment: Hehe, thanks Peter. SP2010 is quite challenging to crack. SP2013 is much better, however some of the areas are still not covered. I'd also would recommend to check out SPMeta2 library to get more insights and code samples.

Comment: the link is dead, that answer should probably be updated

Comment: @baywet, found the content on internet archive. Link updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well the quick stuff first:

A Wiki Page is NOT a publishing page, so you are probably not trying to create a publishing page..

Secondly:

"Page Content" is not an internal name of a SharePoint field / column. They do not contain white space, the actual internal name is "WikiField"

Not sure why it tells you that "Title" is invalid though! But I would guess it is because a field with that internal name does not exist in the list "Documentation"

Comment: Do I need to specify the content type so that it will know which columns are available?

Comment: Could be, sorry but I'm not an expert on Client object model. I just spotted some errors when glancing through your code that I wanted to point out before you had to spot them yourself!

Comment: Oh, but look what I found! http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/95ca3f5d-06e8-479e-8f47-1115f91e0134

Comment: I tried that code, but it kept throwing errors.  I found another example though that worked first try.

Comment: Just to note: as @KevinMcKeown has pointed out below, a Wiki page does not have a title.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the content type for a Wiki Page, or at the default columns list in Library Settings for the Wiki Page library, you will notice that "Title" is not an available column. This may be causing you problems. It also causes an error in SharePoint 2013 when you try to click the "Shared With" ribbon button for a wiki page item.