# Loading XML files into Wiki library on o365/SPO 2013

Tags: 2013, migration, wiki, xml, wiki-pages

We have a bunch of nested and related XML files we want to load or convert into an SPO 2013 Wiki library.

Any smart way to do that?  Anything we can do in general with XML pages and data in SPO?  We'd like to retain relationships and benefit from search without having to reformat or convert them (too much).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the XML structure, but certainly one approach would be to push the content (as HTML) you wish to become the "body" of the Wiki page into the WikiField - a code-based approach can be found here (it does work for 2013 too, however for SharePoint online ) https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Programmatically-change-content-on-a-Wiki-Page-in-SharePoint-2010#.UwCxgvldWpo

For a CSOM based example there is already an answer here [Create a new wiki page using the 2013 Client Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/create-a-new-wiki-page-using-the-2013-client-library)